# Show Map width and height 100% to child when parent div using display:flex property

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to show Map to full width and height inside a flex container, but can't find any perfect solution.

```css
<style>
        body{
        
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .mgrid{
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex: 1;
        }

        header{
          position:relative; height:auto
        }

        .m-grid__item{
          display: flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          flex-direction: row;
          height:100%;
        }
        .m-wrapper{
          flex:1 auto;
          overflow:hidden
          
        }
        .mapdiv{
          position:absolute;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          top:0;bottom:0;
        }
        </style>
```

```html
<body>
              <div class="m-grid">
                  <header>

                  </header>
                  <div class="m-grid__item">
                      <div class="m-wrapper">
                          <div class="mapdiv"></div>

                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
        
        
        </body
```

Want to show Map div to full width and height. Right now map occupies extra height. m-wrapper class not working properly now.

Comment: Please show us how the map is added to the div.

Comment: calling that mapdiv by using Javascript  function like document.getelementbyid('mapdiv').

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your body does not have the entire width and height, and to solve that you have to set first the HTML w & h.

Also, some of the children need 100% w & h to fit the parent's size.

Here's the solution.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.m-grid, .m-grid__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mgrid{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

header{
  position:relative; height:auto
}

.m-grid__item{
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
}
.m-wrapper{
  flex:1 auto;
  overflow:hidden
}

.mapdiv{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: I already set body width and height to 100%.Problem is when we set the parent div to dispaly flex and child element position absolute with width:100% and height:100%

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by using the following two situations

**1. Getting the child of a flex-item to fill height 100%**

- Set position: relative; on the parent of the child.
- Set position:absolute; on the child.
- You can then set width/height as required(100% in my sample).

**2. Fixing the resize scrolling "quirk" in Chrome**

- Put overflow-y: auto; on the scrollable div.
- The scrollable div must have an explicit height specified.
- My sample already has height 100% but if none is already applied you can specify height: 0;